# Add horizontal margin, if space available

Tags: css

I'd like to add a left margin of 40px, *if space available*. And if not enough parent width, let's reduce it.

*Example: if parent is only 420px wide, the margin should be reduced to 20px.*

How to do this?

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#parent {resize: both; border: 2px solid; overflow:auto; width: 500px; }
#margin { display: inline-block; background-color: blue; width: 40px; }
#main { display: inline-block; background-color: red; width: 400px; }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="margin">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="main">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: To confirm: The left `margin` should only ever be a maximum of 40px but, if the parent is too small to contain the child *and* its margin then the margin should be reduced, is that what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: @Shaggy: parent=500 => 40 + 400. parent=412 => 12 + 400. parent=370 => 0 + 370.

Comment: Is "margin" a real element or should it be unoccupied space? Is there real content in main or - if there isn't enough content - should it be narrower than 400px?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  #margin { width: 20px }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0evabfLa/

Here's an animation of the above code, changing the background to yellow when the margin changes.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/c2ab8dd99b93750746403968d7065075.gif]

Comment: Media queries won't work in this instance as the parent element is manually resizable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Oh really, media queries are needed for this? No way with easy CSS tools or `calc(...)` ?

Comment: I don't get the same thing than your animation on Firefox and Chrome. When I resize the parent, it doesn't work as well.

Comment: OP is talking about the width of parent, not viewport. And margin should be 0 below 400px and up to 40px from 400 to 440px (not taking into account the ~4px of whitespace between elements)

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution, using `calc(...)` and `max-width`.

```css
#parent {resize: both; border: 2px solid; overflow:auto; width: 500px; }
#margin { max-width: 40px; width: calc(100% - 404px); display: inline-block; }
#main { background-color: red; width: 400px; display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="margin">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="main">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even without whitespace of 4px and an outline instead of border on parent, plus a `#main { max-width: 400px; }` it doesn't work under 400px: red element goes on a second line. I guess it's because calc() has a negative computed value (like 300px - 404px) but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a flexbox solution with demo cases: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/
Relevant CSS are:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
.margin {
  min-width: 0; /* Necessary under 400px */
  max-width: 40px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
.main {
  width: 400px;
}
```

Margin is allowed to grow up to 40px but must also be set to 0 (flex shrinking never go down to 0 I think as min-width default value is... auto, not 0)